# pushing step functions and lambda through development stages

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-pipelines, aws-serverless, aws-step-functions

I am trying to introduce step functions + lambda functions to the organisation.
we are a .net shop (.net core + Visual Studio + Azure Devops for version control)
We maintain 4 branches of our  code DEV/QA/STAGE/PROD and use pipelines for deployment.

Question:
How do I deploy a SAM from Azure DevOps so that I can have a DEV version(respectively QA/STG) of my step function + Lambda functions that does not affect production

Some of the solutions I have been considering are:

1. Pass the environment to the step function in the input and build arn of the lambda on the fly based on the environment (add :[environment] at the end of the lambda function arn)
2. Use some type of versioning of the step function, maybe even having a different one per environment - This will quadruple at best the number of step functions I need to maintain
3. Use choice steps to call different arn base on the input - this adds complexity and quadruple my code in the step function

My step function is executed from code using the AWS SDK and the invocation can easily either pass an en environment variable or execute a different step function based on the branch and value stored in app config

In addition, I would like to know
how do I create a deployment pipeline code (presumably using the CLI, to create or move my ALIASES to the version of currently attached to the previous environment.
The idea would be deploy $Latest -> attach DEV to $Latest
When pushing to QA, simply move the "QA" Alias to the same version as DEV points to, when deploying to STAGE, move the ALIAS to the QA version etc.

Comment: Are you looking for "Stages": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml?

Comment: Thanks,but not quite.
My issue is more related to cloudformation and AWS step functions/Lambda integration.
It appears, that AWS has limitations at this time and that seamless deployment/promotion of code from DEV to QA to PROD through Azure pipelines has limitations at best. At this time, I plan on deploying code changes to DEV through pipeline, but promotion of code will need to be done in AWSConsole.
if anybody has a better way, please do share.

Comment: You could add an answer for your solution.

Comment: I am also looking something similar to this, our tech stack is in AWS but our DEVOPS setup is in AZURE(TFS). So we need to manage our CFN templates, lambda code and other AWS codes in azure devops for our deployment pipeline/promotion. Any help would be appreciated.